# products upload with csv magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.8, import, products, csv

I am trying to upload products on magento 1.9.0.1 with CSV file. I added one product directly in magento then downloaded CSV file for adding more products on it.

When I import products they do show on magento backend but do not appear on store front end.

Please advise what I would be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you reindex everything? Are the products active, visible and associated to your website?

Comment: Is your product in stock?

Comment: Check the attribute set selected, if you have used sample data then you may need to check attributes. check visibility